# React Native Navigation 4 - Screen doesn't get parameters

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Pretty strange thing cause this function is all over my app but one screen that doesn't get the paramenter I'm passing from the previous one.

1° screen CountdownScreen.js

```
const sessionEnded = () => {
    endSound.play();
    props.navigation.navigate('Daily');
    props.navigation.setParams({time: meditationTime});
    console.log('passing?', meditationTime);
  };
```

(first was `props.navigation.navigate('Daily', {time: meditationTime})`  but didn't work as well )

Daily (the screen that receives, where I move to correctly)

```
const JournalDailyScreen = props => {

const meditationTime = props.navigation.getParam('time');
  console.log('meditation time', meditationTime);
```

... and so on 
I always get `undefined`
Any idea where I mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: 4 sorry I forgot it

Comment: Here is an [example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params/).

Comment: thanks . but as I said I'm passing params in the all app (maybe 30 times?) and works. but here it doesn't